# Ability to distinguish job offers with an external application process

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I have created and crafted a CV on Stack Overflow Jobs for a specific offer, only to discover when I clicked the **apply now** button that the application process is actually external and there's no way to link to that carefully crafted CV.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196073/job-search-filter-by-companies-that-use-the-built-in-application-process) contains a suggestion that actually goes further than what I'm asking below, as it suggests adding a search filter on job offers so as to filter specifically on the nature (internal/external) of the application process.

I obviously made, due to familiarity with some job boards, the wrong assumption that Jobs is "self-contained", so to speak. We should help others not make the same mistake. As is the case with this external application form that I will fill anyway, the work done on the Jobs CV may have to be done again.

Whether the search filter suggested in the aforementioned question has since been implemented or not, information about the application process itself seems to me just as useful as say, the *remote* indicator.

Wouldn't a distinctive badge/icon/marker be added for job offers with an "external" application process add some value?

Comment: Yes, good point. [There's currently an icon that indicates whether a job has an external application](https://goo.gl/3LFVQz). We're currently discussing how we'll make this clearer within the list view.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your feedback.  We recently started a test that, among other things, adds a "Stack Apply" badge to job listings that use the internal application process:

[image: Stack Apply badge]

About half of Stack Overflow Jobs users will see this badge in their job listings.  In about two weeks, we will evaluate whether to deploy this change for all users.  Expect an edit to this answer once we have made a decision.

**Edit:** We decided to roll back this change for all users.  Our testing showed that Stack Overflow Jobs users that saw the change applied to jobs less often than users who still saw the original view.  Because we do not wish to discourage users from applying for jobs, we rolled back the changes today.